# Sharing a variable between controllers in angular.js

Tags: ajax, angularjs, global-variables

I'm new to angular and I'm wondering how I can share a variable between controllers in angular. I'm using the following scripts -

In Main.js:

```
function MainCntl($scope) {
  ---code
}

function SearchCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.url = 'http://10.0.0.13:9000/processAdHoc';
    $scope.errorM = "No results";     
    $scope.search = function() {

        $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.keywords}).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.result = data; 
            alert('yes');
        })
        .
        error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;   
            alert('no');
            $scope.result = "failed";
        });
    };
}
```

In Index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCntl" >
---code
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
     <form class="well form-search">
     <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="tags"></label>
          <a ng-click="search()"><input type="image" src="../../images/search1.png" class="searchbox_submit" /></a>
          <input ng-model="keywords" placeholder="Shadow Search" id="tags" class="input-medium search-query rounded" /> 
     </div>
     </form>
</div>
---code
<p ng-model="result">
     {{result}}
</p>
</body>
```

Everything works well with the ajax I'm sending data and receiving a response, my question is as follows:

In the SearchCtrl function I have a variable called $scope.result that is later referred to in Index.html. If I insert the html code that contains that variable into the SearchCtrl controller it works fine but if it is in the MainCtrl controller it does not work. How can I share this variable between the controllers.

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use a service and inject it to both controllers and refer your scope vars to the services variable.

Example:

```
angular.module("yourAppName", []).factory("myService", function(){

  return {sharedObject: {data: null } }

});

function MainCtrl($scope, myService) {
  $scope.myVar = myService.sharedObject;
}

function SearchCtrl($scope, $http, myService) {
  $scope.myVar = myService.sharedObject;
}
```

In your template do:

```
{{myVar.data}}
```

<kbd>[See an example](http://jsbin.com/ABUpOXA/1)</kbd> Uses Angular v1.1.5

The reason you put it in an inner object is to preserve your references, if you keep it without a "sharedObject", and change that object, your binding will be pointing to the old reference and wouldn't show anything in the template.

Comment: Hi ShaiRez, thanks for the quick answer and the example, but sadly it's still not working... maybe I am not implementing it correctly. I added everything you provided in the example and also changed the template to {{myVar.data}}. Two questions arise, shouldn't I change the templates view also, and also add myVar to the success/error functions of the ajax call?  Thanks again, Gidon

Comment: After reading a bit more I found an easier way to do this with $rootScope... Thanks anyway for your time and kudos on the angular meetups, i'll try to make the next one :)

Comment: @ShaiRez is the preferred model for handling authentication? authenticate in a service (if not logged in already) and return a user model to all controllers that need it?

Comment: It's a different question and if I understand correctly than yes, use a login service or user service to hold communication or properties of that kind

Comment: @Gidon I edited the answer see the added example on jsbin. Also, there was an error in ShaiRez's code.

Comment: Do they have to be in the same js file for this to work?

Comment: Would it work also if each file had its own closure each with its own module?

Comment: @Binvention as long as you load all of the modules as a dependency under the same main module (ng-app) it will work, they don't have to be on the same file