# AngularJS - Router UI - Defining a wildcard parented state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fellas, Fellaaas.
I'm writing from my phone so please excuse me for anything misleading or unclear.
In my app there's a state that can be inherited from any other parent state, called "deals/:dealId:". 
As of now,  I have to define the same state over and over again for any other parent state available, so it could be accessible from any URL on the app.
For example: the parent state "dashboard" has a child state "parent.dashboard.deals", so is another state - "parent.lookup.deals", and so on.
While googling for a solution I found an example on plunkr using a parent state variable definition to create a wildcard'ed state environment: 
.state(currentState+".deals").
"Boy oh boy", I thought to myself. That's exactly what I need. Well, not.
I was testing it and it on a static "currentState" variable and it worked just fine, thought all I had left to do was to dynamically change the currentState variable between parent states switchings.
It appears that when angular is generating the routes for the first time on loading, it takes the default "currentState" var as a string and defines that state static. So, even though I'm changing the default "currentState" var between route changes, the state is only available to the first generated state definition.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing! Dying for a good solution to this problem, it keeps on recurring :p

Comment: I'll try a PR later on

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a feature request on GitHub, just in case I'm the first one in the need for this scenario - or there isn't a proper solution meanwhile for this problem:
github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1014

Anyhow, 
I managed this problem by looping through the parent states and attaching the static child state to them, instead of defining them manually:

```
  angular.forEach(states, function(stateOptions,stateName) {
 $stateProvider.state(stateName, stateOptions.options);
 if (stateOptions.defaultState){
  var dealStateName = stateName+'.deals';
  console.log(dealStateName);
    $stateProvider.state(dealStateName,{
      url: (stateName=='parent.dashboard') ? "deals/:dealId" : "/deals/:dealId",
      views:{
        'fsItem@parent':{
          templateUrl: "/static/html/fsItems/dealNewD.html",
          controller: 'dealCtrl',
        }
      }
    });
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't quite clear, but it sounds like you want a state variable(s) that persists between route changes. I'd suggest using a [factory or service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). Take a look at [Sharing a Variable Between Controllers in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508666/sharing-a-variable-between-controllers-in-angular-js).

Comment: I need a static route of /deals/:dealId to be available via any other parent route (dashboard/deals/123 [parent.dashboard.deals], search/:query/deals/123 [parent.search.deals], profile/:id/deals/123 [parent.profile.deals] and so on).